# Android sliding menu to change content on page can this be done?

Tags: android

The main page has a horizontalScrollView across the top and a number of TextView text fields within it. I would like to be able to scroll and click on any on the TextView text and it change the RelativeLayout to match the selection made in the HorizontalScrollView.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="70dp" android:id="@+id/EditTOne" android:text="tOne"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="70dp" android:id="@+id/EditTTwo" android:text="tTwo"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="70dp" android:id="@+id/EditTThree" android:text="tThree"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="70dp" android:id="@+id/EditTFour" android:text="tFour"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="70dp" android:id="@+id/EditTFive" android:text="tFive"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="70dp" android:id="@+id/EditTSix" android:text="tSix"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="70dp" android:id="@+id/EditTSeven" android:text="tSeven"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have a second layout page called tone which would be linked to the menu option tOne in the HorizontalScrollView.

tone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="This is tOne"></TextView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

The main activity will flag if one of the first 4 options are selected by writing to the LogCat. Is it possible to display the tone.xml within the relativelayout if the user clicks the tOne option from the HorizontalScrollView? Then if the user selects tTwo display ttwo.xml in the RelativeLayoutView etc?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SlideMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView tOne, tTwo, tThree, tFour, tFive, tSix, tSeven, tEight, tNine, tTen;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        RelativeLayout vSpace = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

        tOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditTOne);
        tTwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditTTwo);
        tThree = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditTThree);
        tFour = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditTFour);
        tFive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditTFive);
        tSix = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditTSix);
        tSeven = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EditTSeven);



        tOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        tTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
        tThree.setOnClickListener(this);
        tFour.setOnClickListener(this);
        tFive.setOnClickListener(this);
        tSix.setOnClickListener(this);
        tSeven.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()) {

        //--------------
        case R.id.EditTOne:
            System.out.println("Text One pressed");

        break;
        case R.id.EditTTwo:
            System.out.println("Text Two pressed");
        break;
        case R.id.EditTThree:
            System.out.println("Text Three pressed");
        break;
        case R.id.EditTFour:
            System.out.println("Text Four pressed");
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is fairly simple. I added

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.tone, vSpace);
```

after you print "Text One Pressed". Be sure to make `vSpace` a field first.

To do this with all of them, call

```
vSpace.removeAllViews()
```

before you inflate each view.

Comment: Thanks Craigy that works well. Would I be able to animate the transition from tOne to tTwo. For example slide one layout out and slide the next one in?

Comment: @John Please ask that in a new question.

Comment: I honestly haven't done much with animations, but I tried out the example from [here](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html) with some success. I was able to get it to switch views between two of them, but the logic becomes difficult with more views as it appears the only methods available are `showNext` and `showPrevious`. Maybe you can keep track of which view you are on yourself and then call `showNext` repeatedly? Perhaps you should post a new question.